# Why am I unable to make my animation duration 0 seconds? How would I correctly do it?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-animation, calayer

I'm trying to build a pie chart animation with Core Animation, and I'm having trouble. I want to be able to animate it (hence the use of Core Animation) but also be able to turn animation off easily.

```
- (void)setProgress:(CGFloat)progress animated:(BOOL)animated {
    self.innerPie.hidden = NO;

    self.innerPie.strokeEnd = progress;

    if (animated) {
        CABasicAnimation *pathAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"strokeEnd"];
        pathAnimation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear];
        pathAnimation.duration = (animated) ? 2.0 : 0.0;
        pathAnimation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:self.progress];
        pathAnimation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:progress];
        [self.innerPie addAnimation:pathAnimation forKey:@"strokeEndAnimation"];
    }

    self.progress = progress;
}
```

That's my code. If I set `animated` to `NO`, the animation still occurs, just much faster. Why? How would I change it so it's instant?

Comment: What is it that animates that you don't like? Is it the change in `strokeEnd` or the change is `self.progress`?

Comment: (And what is `strokeEnd` anyway? It would be cool if you could show a picture of what this code actually does. :)

Comment: I think the question is, why is the animation occurring if `animated` is `NO`? - the whole block should be skipped resulting in an "instant" change to strokeEnd. Have you tried setting a breakpoint and stepping through the method to confirm that the block inside `if (animated)` isn't executing?  Is it possible that this call is nested inside another animation block?

Comment: So it fills in a circle in a clock-wise fashion, similar to the iOS 7 app downloading animation. `strokeEnd`, as I understand it is where to stop stroking the path ([see here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CAShapeLayer_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008314-CH1-SW15)). Here's a picture of it mid-animation: http://i.imgur.com/OkPx5wW.png And I'd like it to be able to instantly jump to that point instead of animating to it like a clock.

Comment: Yup, in that case my answer is right. Merely calling `self.innerPie.strokeEnd = progress;` is what is causing the animation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`strokeEnd` is an animatable property of a layer - in this case, a CAShapeLayer (otherwise you could not attempt to animate using `animationWithKeyPath`).

Well, setting a layer's animatable property animates the change! That is called (by me at least) *implicit animation*.

So this one line, all by itself, causes animation:

```
self.innerPie.strokeEnd = progress;
```

To prevent that, you must turn off implicit animation temporarily. There are various ways to do that; the usual thing is to disable it at the transaction level by calling the CATransaction class method `setDisableActions:` (to YES, obviously).

Comment: The `CATransaction` worked for the most part, but the opacity still animates: http://i.imgur.com/bD7F7Lq.png (Edit: Nevermind, was due to my poor placement of `setHidden:`)

Comment: You didn't turn off animation in time. You must do it before changing any animatable layer properties!

Comment: Here's the section of my book on implicit layer animation: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch17.html#_implicit_layer_animation